# Function default parameters are ignored

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, g++

For this simplified piece of code I'm getting following error:

> error: too few arguments to function
>     std::cout << f();

```
int g(int a = 2, int b = 1)
{
    return a + b;
}

template<class Func>
void generic(Func f)
{
    std::cout << f();
}

int main()
{
    generic(g);
}
```

I cannot clue the reason for why the default parameters of function `f` are not passing into a function `generic`. It behaves like `f` doesn't have any default parameters ...

What's wrong there?

How do I forward default parameters correctly?

Comment: I'm guessing that the time the function pointer is passed, it already selected an overload for the function that needs 2 parameters.

Comment: Language lawyer alert… ``a`` and ``b`` are function *parameters*. These parameters have default *arguments* of 2 and 1, rsp.  So ``a`` is a parameter, and the value of ``a`` at run time is the argument.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`g` may have default arguments, but the type of `&g` is still `int(*)(int, int)`, which is not a type that can be called with no arguments. Within `generic`, we can't differentiate that - we've already lost the context about default arguments.

You can just wrap `g` in a lambda to preserve the context:

```
generic([]{ return g(); });
```

Comment: is there any possibility (without `bind`) to get a `int(*)(int)` or `int(*)()` from `g` ?

Comment: Maybe soon we will able to do this `generic([]() => g());`, right? :P (thanks)

Comment: @tobi303 You can't do it with `bind` at all - same problem as here. Has to be a lambda.

Comment: hmm that's interesting, it seems to be working that way. But how does lambda preserve the context ?

Comment: @Barry yes. Its the first time I think about it and somehow makes completely sense

Comment: @ampawd Because `g()` is a valid expression, you're invoking it directly by name. It's the name lookup via `g` that gets you the default arguments, not through the type of `g`

Answer (score 7):

I think the error message to this code quite nicely demonstrates why this isn't possible:

```
int g(int a=0,int b=0){return 0;}

typedef int (*F1)(int);

int main() {
    F1 x = g;
}

error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'F1' (aka 'int (*)(int)') with
an lvalue of type 'int (int, int)': different number of parameters (1 vs 2)
    F1 x = g;
       ^   ~
```

Even with default parameters, the type of `g` is still

```
int (*) (int,int)
```

and that's what gets deduced when you instantiate the template.

If for some reason you cannot use C++11 or later (i.e. no lambdas, see Barry's answer) and you don't mind a little boilerplate, then you can use a function object:

```
#include <iostream>

struct g_functor {
    int operator()(int a=0,int b=0){ return a;}
};

template <typename T> void foo(T t) { t(); }

int main() { foo(g_functor()); }
```

Note that you have to create an instance of `g_functor` to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: If you're going to go boilerplate, you should make `g` a function object instead - so you can still do `generic(g)`

Comment: yeah, nice solution with function object as well

Comment: @ampawd function objects are just the poor mans lambdas (or lambdas are just function objects with some fancier syntax). I was just curious to see how one would do it in C++98. For me this always helps to better understand the C++11 features as most of them were invented to overcome C++98 shortcomings